# Check db value in rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Is it good to check db value in view, not in controller? 
Now i have such view:

```
- @articles.each do |art|
  -if art.QUANTITYM > 0
    =art.PRICEM
     %br
       = art.PRICEM * @currency.currencyvalue
```

On my previous rails 3.0.9 project (now 3.2.6), all was good, but now it gives me:

> undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass

Also my method in controller look's like this:

```
def category
    @type_details = Type.find_by_TYP_ID(params[:type])
    @search_trees = SearchTree.find(:all, :include => [:designation], :conditions => { :STR_ID_PARENT => params[:cat]})


    @strlookup = StrLookup.find(:all, :conditions => { :STL_STR_ID => params[:cat]})
    @genart = GenericArticle.all(:conditions => { :GA_ID => @strlookup.map(&:STL_GA_ID)})

    @type = params[:type]
    @la_typs = LinkLaTyp.find(:all, :conditions => { :LAT_TYP_ID => params[:type], :LAT_GA_ID => @genart.map(&:GA_ID)})    


    data = "{ label : 1,  children : [{label : 1},{label : 1}]  }"
    #puts JSON.pretty_generate(data)


    if @genart.blank?
      @articles = nil

    else
      @linkla = LinkArt.find(:all, :conditions => { :LA_ID => @la_typs.map(&:LAT_LA_ID), :LA_GA_ID => @genart.map(&:GA_ID)})    
      @pre_articles = Article.find(:all, :include => [:supplier], :conditions => {:ART_ID => @linkla.map(&:LA_ART_ID)}, :order => "SUPPLIERS.SUP_BRAND, ARTICLES.QUANTITYM asc")
      @articles = Kaminari.paginate_array(@pre_articles).page(params[:page]).per(20)
    end


    @currency = Currency.find(:first)

    #@cart = current_cart #NOTE THIS!!!
    respond_to do |format|

      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @search_trees }
      #format.json { render :json => @search_trees }
    end
  end
```

How to check my db Quantity and in view accoding to value display price? Or it is "criminal", and i must do this in controller? Than how to do this check in controller and display it in view?

Note, this is non-my db, so it's very huge, and have a lot of tables, and data in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problem checking it in the view. You get the error because `art.QUANTITYM` is `nil`. To prevent this error you have to check if it's `nil` first and then if it's bigger than zero:

```
- if art.QUANTITYM.present? && art.QUANTITYM > 0
```

Comment: Don't need to do art.QUANTITYM.present?, if art.QUANTITYM && art.QUANTITYM > 0 should work

Comment: @SKR, no it DOES NOT work. If `art.QUANTITYM == 0` your code will return `true`, which is not what you want.

Comment: @PavelBY, you're welcome. See the comment above. You shouldn't listen to SKR.